# How to fix NotImplementedError: Could not find signature for cell2mat: <ndarray> while using mat2py library

Tags: python, matlab

I am trying to convert matlab code to python code
Here is the matlab code

```
close all;
load('Workspace_training.mat/Workspace_training.mat');
y = svm(sD_colorado_complete_unlabeled.data(:,:) )
y_true = cell2mat(sD_colorado_train_labeled.labels)
figure(1)
subplot(1, 2, 1)
ylim = ([0, 3000])
histogram(y)
subplot(1, 2, 2)
ylim = ([0, 3000])
histogram(y_true)close all;
```

i am using mat2py library in python to convert matlab code to python code

here is the python code in mat2py folder

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.io
from precision import Precision
p = Precision()
mat = scipy.io.loadmat('Workspace_training.mat/Workspace_training.mat')
y = svm(mat['sD_colorado_complete_unlabeled']); print y
y_true = p.cell2mat(mat['sD_colorado_train_labeled']); print(y_true)
figure(1)
a = plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
ylim = [0, 3000]; print (ylim)
plt.histogram(y)
b =plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
ylim = [0, 3000]; print (ylim)
p.histc(y_true)
```

i am getting error
NotImplementedError: Could not find signature for cell2mat: